# Django showing Zen Poetry every time on running server

Tags: django, django-models

[vscode-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiCBv.png)

I am pretty sure everything is in order but it keep showing this poetry upon running the server or refreshing the server (by saving python file).
Please help, this is annoying.

Answer (score 5):

The Zen of Python is printed [by the `import this` easter egg](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/this.py).

```
>>> import this
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters
...
>>>
```

Find wherever you do

```
import this
```

in your codebase and get rid of it.

Comment: It will also appear if you have imported something from `this`, ie. `from this import d`. I just got confused by this as I let VS Code automatically add an import without realising it.